# Finding all vectors of length $1$ that are perpendicular to a given two dimensional vector

Tags: solution-verification, vectors

Below is a problem I made up. I would expect there to be around $2$ vectors
that meet the given criterion. However,  I could not convince myself that there
are $4$ vectors that meet the given criterion.

Problem:

Find all vectors that are perpendicular to the vector $(2,3)$ and have
length $1$.

Answer:

If two vectors are perpendicular then there dot product is $0$.
\begin{align*}
(u_1,u_2) \cdot (2,3) &= 0 \\
2u_1 + 3u_2 &= 0 \\
\sqrt{ u_1^2 + u_2^2 } &= 1 \\
u_1^2 + u_2^2 &= 1 
\end{align*}
Now we have two equations with two unknowns.
\begin{align*}
2u_1 &= -\dfrac{3u_2}{2} \\
u_1^2 &= \sqrt{ 1 - u_2^2 } \\
 \sqrt{ 1 - u_2^2 } &= -\dfrac{3u_2}{2} \\
 1 - u_2^2 &= \dfrac{9u_2^2}{4} \\
\dfrac{13u_2^2}{4} &= 1 \\
13u_2^2 &= 4 \\
u_2 &= \pm \dfrac{ 2 } {\sqrt{13}} \\
\end{align*}
We will first consider the case where $u_2$ is positive.
\begin{align*}
2u_1 + 3\left(  \dfrac{ 2 } {\sqrt{13}} \right)  &= 0 \\
u_1 + \dfrac{ 3 } {\sqrt{13}} &= 0 \\
u_1 &=  -\dfrac{ 3 } {\sqrt{13}}
\end{align*}
Now we will first consider the case where $u_2$ is negative.
\begin{align*}
2u_1 + 3\left(  \dfrac{ -2 } {\sqrt{13}} \right)  &= 0 \\
u_1 - \left(  \dfrac{ 3 } {\sqrt{13}} \right)  &= 0 \\
u_1 &=  \dfrac{ 3 } {\sqrt{13}}
\end{align*}
Hence our two vectors are:
$\left(  -\dfrac{ 3 } {\sqrt{13}}, \dfrac{ 2 } {\sqrt{13}} \right) $
and $\left( \dfrac{ 3 } {\sqrt{13}}, -\dfrac{ 2 } {\sqrt{13}} \right) $.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Is the title a typo? The title specified a vector of length $0$, but in the body of the question, you specified a vector of length $1$.

Comment: @VTand The title should have said length 1.

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect there would be four vectors? There are indeed two vectors, if we're constrained to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @BrianTung I was told by a friend, who has a BS in math that he thought there were 4. However, he got his degree a long time ago and his skills have deteriorated.

Comment: Where did the $1$ in $(1,2,3)$ come from? Sometimes a picture is pretty insightful. You can draw this and see the answer is two.

Comment: @TedShifrin The 1 should not be there. I will fix it.

Comment: There would be four if we were working in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @BrianTung It seems to me that if we are working in $R^3$ then there are an infinite amount of answers. That is if you view the original vector as a pipe you can have a perpendicular vector coming off at any angle.

Comment: @Bob: Duh, yes you're right. I was thinking mutually perpendicular.